# Site requires login. How to publish login-free RSS feed?

Tags: rss, authentication

The WordPress site is for internal use only and as such I've set it up so it requires users to be logged in before they can see any of its pages. As a result, my RSS feed url won't work without authentication.

The feed is needed for a digital signage system. Is there a way to send the login credentials for a user, or some sort of key, along with the URL so that authentication takes place instantly? Or somehow unprotect just the RSS feed page? I have seen some plugins for special "feed keys" but I don't think that really helps in my situation.

Thanks!

Comment: Without knowing what your plugin is or what it does, it´s kinda hard to answer this question. You might have better luck asking the plugin author for guidance on how to allow the RSS feed to be accessed.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. That's a bit of a red herring -- I only intended to indicate that I've made the blog inaccessible to users who are not logged in. I don't have any particular preference as to how I achieve that, or which plugin I use. The real question is, how can I get at the RSS feed when login is required?

Comment: arguing with people about the validity of your question has very little impact. Question should contain all relevant details, if your question do not contain the details on how you protect the content then it is impossible to answer it. In its corrent state the alternative to close voting it is simply not to answer it so if you actually want to get answer please edit and improve your question and make it contain all the relevant details

Comment: Maybe you could use a conditional like ``if( is_feed() ) { ...``. But as said, without knowing more about your setup this is really hard/imposible to answer.